# How Do I Skip The Creation Of A Terraform Resource?

Tags: terraform, azure-pipelines

My terraform script is setup up for a web app in production.
As part of that I have Azure DDoS protection enabled.

However, this is really expensive compared to the rest of the infrastructure.
For this reason, I don't want to create it for my development environment.

I run terraform using Azure pipelines so I would like to configure the pipeline to optionally not create it. e.g. with a variable in the pipeline

Is there an option I can pass to terraform to skip this resource?

Assuming there *is* an option and I *can* skip the ddos resource, will the creation of the vnet fail in the snippet below if it doesn't exist?

```
#---------------------------------------
#    DDOS Protection Plan Definition
#---------------------------------------

resource "azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan" "ddos" {
  name                = var.ddos_plan_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

#---------------------------------------
#            vNet Definition
#---------------------------------------

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {

  name                = lower("${local.vNet_id}-${var.location_id}-${var.env_id}-1")
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = var.address_space

  ddos_protection_plan {
    id     = azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan.ddos.id
    enable = true
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.rg
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it is to use the `count` meta-argument [1]. For example, create a variable with a name `create_ddos_protection_plan`, set it to be of type `bool` and by default set it to `false`:

```
variable "create_ddos_protection_plan" {
  description = "Whether to create DDoS resource or not."
  type = bool
  
  default = false
}

resource "azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan" "ddos" {
  count               = var.create_ddos_protection_plan ? 1 : 0
  name                = var.ddos_plan_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
```

Later on if you decide you want to create it, you can set the value of the variable to `true` or remove the `count` meta-argument completely.

The `vnet` creation would fail if the resource does not exist based on the current setup.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count

Comment: count = 0 will destroy the resource, question is "how to skip"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `count` meta-argument](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) to dynamically choose how many instances of a particular resource to create, including possibly choosing to create *zero* of them, which therefore effectively disables the resource altogether:

```
variable "enable_ddos_protection" {
  type = bool

  default = true
}

resource "azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan" "ddos" {
  count = var.enable_ddos_protection ? 1 : 0

  name                = var.ddos_plan_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
```

Since the number of instances of this resource is now dynamic, `azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan.ddos` will appear as a list of objects instead of a single object. Therefore you'll also need to change how you refer to it in the virtual network configuration.

The most direct way to declare that would be to use a [`dynamic` block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) to tell Terraform to generate one `ddos_protection_plan` block per instance of that resource, so there will be no blocks of that type if there are no protection plan instances:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name = lower("${local.vNet_id}-${var.location_id}-${var.env_id}-1")

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = var.address_space

  dynamic "ddos_protection_plan" {
    for_each = azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan.ddos
    content {
      id     = ddos_protection_plan.value.id
      enable = true
    }
  }
}
```

(I removed the `depends_on` declaration here because it was redundant with the reference in the `resource_group_name` argument, but the `dynamic` block is the main point of this example.)

Comment: I knew I was missing something, great addition to my answer. :)